# python submodule shadowing other package

Tags: python, import, python-module

Consider these imports

```
# main.py
from b.c import X
from a.b import Y
```

and

```
# a/b.py
from b.c import X
```

When starting main.py. the "from b.c" import works, but inside a/b.py it seems that python now tries to resolve the import as "a/b/c.py. Why is that so and is there a way to avoid this (except renaming b.py)?

Comment: you should set your PYTHONPATH to point at your folder 'a' then it will be included for imports .... or just make sure to call it from the main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems that all I need is to change

```
# a/b.y
from __future__ import absolute_import
from b.c import X
```